# Github visible actions

Tags: github

I've been invited to a repo by an organization for a take home interview project. I'm concerned that if I accept it that it will show up on the github feed and my coworkers are able to see it. Especially when I make commits and pull request. Is this true? Can it be prevented?

Comment: Is this a public repository?

Comment: @Ethan Looks private. I was invited as a collaborator.

Comment: Just create a new (anonymous like) github account?

Comment: To add on make sure the 2 accounts have NOTHING similar or anything connected to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will show up on your feed. (Kinda) It will say `x contributions in private repositories`. You can see an example below from my account:

[image]

People that do have view access or higher will see the repository and what you did, PRs, issues, etc.

Comment: Ok that fine as long as the user can't find anymore details.